# Powershell: reference an object property in another object property from within the same object?

Tags: powershell, object, hashtable

Evening folks, just a small question, if it a possibility.

I know I can do it by calling it as an empty object then adding properties one by one.

```
$Obj = New-Object PSObject
$Obj.name = “hello”
$Obj.type = $Obj.name ‘+’ “world”
```

Is there a way to do this as one property line?

```
$Obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
Name = “hello”
Type = $Obj.name ‘+’ “world”
}
```

Comment: You can do it with a class but what's the problem you're trying to solve? What is stopping you from doing just `Type = 'hello' + 'world'` in your example?

Comment: It’s mainly a curiosity thing but. Specifically I have an object where I define the installer as getting the most recent file in the folder. And then I pull the installer version and instead of copying the code again for that property I’d like to just reference the property

Comment: Well you can do it with a class but it wouldn't look the same as you have. The argument would only be what you're using for `name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help you accomplish what you're looking for using a [PowerShell `class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.2):

- Definition

```
class SomeClass {
    [string] $Name
    [string] $Type

    SomeClass() { }
    SomeClass([string] $Name, [string] $Type) {
        # ctor for custom Type
        $this.Name = $Name
        $this.Type = $Type
    }

    static [SomeClass] op_Explicit([string] $Name) {
        # explicit cast using only `Name`
        return [SomeClass]::new($Name, $Name + 'World')
    }
}
```

Now you can instantiate using a custom value for the `Type`:

```bash
PS ..\> [SomeClass]@{ Name = 'hello'; Type = 'myCustomType' }

Name  Type
----  ----
hello myCustomType
```

Or let the [explicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) handle the predefined value for the `Type` property based on the `Name` argument:

```bash
PS ..\> [SomeClass] 'hello'

Name  Type
----  ----
hello helloWorld
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! And something for me to give a look into. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

[Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73967674/45375) shows how to solve your problem via defining a `class` that creates a *dedicated .NET type*.

However, you can avoid creating a dedicated .NET class using the following **workaround**, which uses an *auxiliary variable* and the fact that enclosing a variable assignment in [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) passes an assignment's value *through*:

```bash
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{
  Name = ($name = 'hello')  # assign 'hello' to $name and pass the value through
  Type = $name + 'world'    # use the value assigned to $name above
}
```

Note: This **relies on the *order* of property definitions**: *derived* property values must be placed *after* the ones in which the aux. variables are defined.

Outputting `$obj` to the display prints:

```
Name  Type
----  ----
hello helloworld
```

See also:

- [GitHub issue #13782](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13782), which asks for a *built-in* mechanism for internally cross-referencing the entries of hashtable, which could equally apply to a custom-object literal.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, that's a great and simple workaround which is easy to maintain :-)